# Editing bot messages on telethon

Tags: bots, telegram, telethon

I'm trying to create a telegram bot with telethon that uses inline buttons and can't seem to figure out how to edit my messages after a button is pressed. I have something like this to start:

```
@bot.on(events.NewMessage(pattern='/start'))
async def send_welcome(event):

    await bot.send_message(event.from_id, 'What food do you like?', buttons=[
        Button.inline('Fruits', 'fruit'),
        Button.inline('Meat', 'meat')
    ])

@bot.on(events.CallbackQuery(data='fruit'))
async def handler(event):

    await bot.edit_message(event.from_id, event.id, 'What fruits do you like?', buttons=[
        Button.inline('Apple', 'apple'),
        Button.inline('Pear', 'pear'),
        ...
    ])
```

After clicking on the Fruits button, nothing happens. Would love some help on this!

Comment: Edits through `CallbackQuery` are a bit special, try using `await event.edit(...)` instead.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you so much for your help, it's working!

Answer (score 1):

Like this u can edit

```
message = await client.send_message(chat, 'hello')
await client.edit_message(chat, message, 'hello!')
# or
await client.edit_message(chat, message.id, 'hello!!')
# or
await client.edit_message(message, 'hello!!!')
```

from the official documentation of telethon

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest a solution.
It implements the exact idea of mr. Snowman's question. But it might be useful to place conditions inside the handler.

```py
from telethon import TelegramClient, sync, events, Button 

api_id = xxx
api_hash = 'xxx'
bot = TelegramClient('session', api_id, api_hash)

@bot.on(events.NewMessage(pattern='/start'))
async def send_welcome(event):
    await bot.send_message(event.sender_id,
        'What food do you like?',
        buttons=[
            Button.inline('Fruits', 'fruit'),
            Button.inline('Meat', 'meat')
        ]
    )

@bot.on(events.CallbackQuery(data='fruit'))
async def handler(event):
    await bot.edit_message(event.sender_id, event.message_id,
        'What fruits do you like?',
        buttons=[
            Button.inline('Apple', 'apple'),
            Button.inline('Pear', 'pear')
        ]
    )

bot.start()
bot.run_until_disconnected()
```